# Notify user when they got a letter correct in a char list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about telling the user when they've got the correct letter in a list? Only way I know of is to insert the index, but that doesn't feel very flexible, especially when the words vary in length.

```
import random

possibleWords = [["apple"], ["grapefruit"], ["pear"]]
randomWord = random.choice(possibleWords)
anotherWord = ''.join(randomWord)
finalWord = list(anotherWord)
maxTries = list(range(0, 11))
attemptsMade = 0
triesLeft = 10

print("Hangman!")
print("\nYou got {} tries before he dies!".format(maxTries[10]))
print("There's {} possible letters.".format(len(finalWord)))

for tries in maxTries:
    userChoice = input("> ")

    if userChoice == finalWord[0]:
        print("You got the first letter correct! It is {}.".format(finalWord[0]))

    else:
        print("Ouch! Wrong letter! {} tries remaining.".format(triesLeft))

    attemptsMade += 1
    triesLeft -= 1
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that need fixed in your code. Perhaps you should start with a [Python Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/)?

Answer (score 0):

Talking about characters in lists, or - what i think is more likely in your case - chars in words you can just check for

```
if userChoice in finalWord:
        # [...] do stuff here
```

and further on use the index function to determine the position (or positions if multiple occurence).

```
finalWord.index(userChoice)
```

You could sure also go the way using index() function directly and work your way using the return values.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's "in" keyword to check if something is within a list/iterable.

```
if userChoice in finalWord:
```

Though for this, I'd just use regex or list comprehension to get the indexes while you are at it, since you might want them for the game.

```
char_indexes = [i for (i, l) in enumerate(finalWord) if l == userChoice]
if len(char_indexes):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set for the letters that are in the word, and whenever the player guesses a letter, check if the letter is still in the set. If it’s not, it was a wrong letter; if it is, then remove that letter and just continue. If the set is empty at some point, then the player guessed all letters of the word.

Something to get you started:

```
def hangman (word):
    letters = set(word.lower())
    attempts = 5
    while attempts > 0:
        guess = input('Guess a character ')
        if guess[0].lower() in letters:
            print('That was correct!')
            letters.remove(guess[0])
        else:
            print('That was not correct!')
            attempts -= 1

        if not letters:
            print('You solved the word:', word)
            return

hangman('grapefruit')
```